# How to use an item from one Observable in another

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I replace the `123` with the results of the router params (I'm using Angular 2)?

```
this.data = this.apollo.watchQuery({
  query: query,
  variables: {
    custNum: 123
  }
})
  .map(({data}) => data.allCustomers.nodes);
```

Normally, I would access params like this...

```
this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => this.customerService.getCustomer(+params['id']))
  .subscribe((results: any) => this.data = results);
```

But I no longer have a customerService, and want to use the apollo query instead.  But not quite sure how to put these together?

Comment: Cant you add watchQuery inside subscribe of route.params?

Answer (score 0):

Your `watchQuery` is not reactive in that you can dynamically replace the `variables` passed to it. You would need to setup a new `watchQuery` whenever your custNum changes and abandon the previous Observable. You can do this by `.switch()` which unsubscribes from the previous Observable when a new Observable is emitted by the stream.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .map(customerNumber => this.apollo.watchQuery({
    query: query,
    variables: {
      custNum: customerNumber
    }
  }) /* returns ObservableQuery */
  .switch() /* unsubscribes previous watchQuery, subscribes new one */
  .map(({data}) => data.allCustomers.nodes);
```